# How to add all titles to queue in Handbrake on OS X

Tags: macos, handbrake

How do I easily add all titles to the queue in Handbrake on OS X and ideally automatically include the title number in the file name as well?

Comment: Can you not just from from chapter X to chapter Y in one go? Handbrake will automatically add chapter marks for navigation. If you're trying to make each chapter a separate file I don't think there's an easy way to do this from the Handbrake UI.

Comment: What's happening is that I put in the DVD and each of the chapters is listed in the dropdown. I have to then navigate to each chapter, change the filename and add each to the queue indivually. A bit of a pain.

Comment: But you can pick a start and end chapter and rip it all as one big file. There's no way to have it do auto-naming the way you're asking for AFAIK.

Comment: Also, have a look at some of the nightly builds.

Answer (score 18):

On the File menu, there's an Add All Titles To Queue... option.

Comment: Remember to properly select the language(s) you want in the Preferences, because it gets resetted to the defaults no matter what you select prior to clicking the "Add all titles to queue" option. See: https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/Queue

Comment: I don't get why this was downvoted - of all the answers here, this is the only one that actually helped *me*.

Comment: Note, for me if I didn't have "Use auto naming..." checked in prefs the Add All Titles function crashes handbrake.

Comment: It is visible if you press option (alt)

Answer (score 15):

From the Handbrake manual, if you tick the checkbox "Use Auto Naming..." it will add title numbers to each file name when it adds it to the queue. I usually use this, then delete those I don't want from the queue.

> Auto Naming output files
>   HandBrake has the ability to automatically name the output file when you change the "Title" dropdown.

This feature can be controlled in HandBrakes Preferences window.

Answer (score 9):

To do large batches of titles without a lot of manual work, download the [command line version of Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/downloads2.php) and then run a script, e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {2..70}
do
   echo Doing track number $i...
   ./HandBrakeCLI -t $i -i /Volumes/MX1-0N-NW1_DES --preset iPad -o X-Men_Vol1_Disk1_Title$i.mp4
done
```

Answer (score 2):

those are titles, not chapters in the dropdown. You can set it to append the title number after your preset filename ({source}{title}{chapters}), but I haven't figured out how to make them do all of them without pulling down each one.

Answer (score 0):

In [HandBrake 1.0.7 for Windows](https://handbrake.fr/rotation.php?file=HandBrake-1.0.7-i686-Win_GUI.exe&old=true), one can use: `Add to Queue` -> `Add All`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. In the Handbrake menu, click `Settings...`

[image]

2. Enable `Automatically name output files`:

[image]

3. Open the `File` menu:

[image]

4. Press your keyboard's `option` key and keep it pressed, the menu magically changes to this:

[image]

5. Click `Add All Titles to Queue`